# Sprockets Assets not compiled when visiting with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sprockets

The issue I'm having is that the generated asset path does not point to anything -- my project directory doesn't change / sprockets doesn't build / compress the js.

in my erb:

```
  <%= javascript_tag 'app' %>
```

in my app.rb (main sinatra file)

```
  register AssetPipeline
```

in asset_pipeline.rb

```
require 'sprockets-helpers'

module AssetPipeline
  module_function

  def registered(app)
    app.set :assets, assets = Sprockets::Environment.new(app.settings.root)
    app.set :assets_path, -> { File.join(public_folder, "assets") }
    app.set :assets_precompile, %w(app.js)

    assets.append_path('assets/javascripts')

    app.configure :development do
      assets.cache = Sprockets::Cache::FileStore.new('./tmp')

      app.get '/assets/*' do
        env['PATH_INFO'].sub!(%r{^/assets}, '')
        settings.assets.call(env)
      end
    end

    app.configure :production do
      Sprockets.register_compressor 'application/javascript', :uglify, Sprockets::UglifierCompressor
      Sprockets.js_compressor = :uglify
    end

    Sprockets::Helpers.configure do |config|
      config.environment = assets
      config.prefix      = '/assets'
      config.debug       = true if app.development?
      if app.production?
        config.digest      = true
        config.manifest    = Sprockets::Manifest.new(
          assets,
          File.join(app.assets_path, "manifesto.json")
        )
      end
    end

    app.helpers Sprockets::Helpers
  end
end
```

I'm running the app with

```
RACK_ENV=production puma
```

As you can see in the last snippet, I have the Uglifier compressor setup.

The problem I see in the browser is that 
`/assets/app-digesthash.js` is not found (and the sinatra/puma log shows a 404 as well)

Relevant gem versions:

```
puma (3.11.0)
sinatra (2.0.0)
sprockets (4.0.0.beta6)
sprockets-helpers (1.2.1)
```

Comment: I switched to ActionMailer. `gem 'actionmailer', require: 'action_mailer'` and my problem went away :-\

Comment: if your question is solved please mark it as solved.

Comment: my question is not solved. I still have no idea how to fingerprint assets

Answer (score 0):

The block `app.get '/assets/*' do` seems to be scoped wrongly. Move it to the top outside of the block it's in (and to be safe, after the configuration for production) and it should kick in properly, like so:

```
app.configure :development do
    assets.cache = Sprockets::Cache::FileStore.new('./tmp')
end 

app.configure :production do
    Sprockets.register_compressor 'application/javascript', :uglify, Sprockets::UglifierCompressor
    Sprockets.js_compressor = :uglify
end 

app.get '/assets/*' do
    env['PATH_INFO'].sub!(%r{^/assets}, '') 
    settings.assets.call(env)
end
```